# "built-in" progressBar technique for Webview on Android

Tags: android, webview

How do I add a loading bar for Webview on Android?

I have the following working Webview code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser (commented out, we'll allow fice URLs only)
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aiming to add a simple prograss bar/loading bar but can't seem to find how to do this.

Comment: you want show progress when load webview ?

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Yes, that is correct. Ideally, the built in loading bar.

Comment: OK. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser (commented out, we'll allow fice URLs only)
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

> Don't forget to Add this in your XML before `Web View`.

```
<ProgressBar
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the update, however, can you kindly edit your answer and implement this code with my own code. I can't seem to understand exact where I would paste this within the code

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Check i have edited in your code.Please apply my change to your OP code.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tested it but I'm getting the following error: http://i.imgur.com/nyFaINh.png

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Ohhhhh!! my mistaken. Replace your web view object their that is `mWebView` instead of `web`. *I have edited check it changes.*

Comment: I just tested it, I could run it but no progress bar is shown. I did add the XML. Can you test it yourself and confirm if it's showing a progress bar? Thanks again for hanging in there.

Comment: I performed tests with this too, the progress bar is not displayed. Interesting approach nonetheless. Would be nice to see it working. +1

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Actually `ProgressBar` is showing for seconds of fraction below `toolbar` or may be `actionbar`. It is gone immediate after page loads. i have checked that.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson The `Progress Bar` definitely showing with this code. i have checked twice.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement custom WebViewClient

```
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // here show your progress view
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

and custom WebViewClient:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }); // here hide progress view
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer and add my own code and implement the progress bar that way?

Comment: Interesting approach, but this is not an *update* of OP's original code. I think what he wants is his own code updated so he understand how to do this...

Comment: may be ). and for my opinion better start loading just before loadUrl, coz on event will be bit delay before progress will be showed.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code. try it!!!

Create class MyWebChromeClient.class

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
private ProgressListener mListener;

public MyWebChromeClient(ProgressListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    mListener.onUpdateProgress(newProgress);
    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
}

public interface ProgressListener {
    public void onUpdateProgress(int progressValue);
}
}
```

in WebviewActivity.class

```
public class WebviewActivity extends BaseActivity implements MyWebChromeClient.ProgressListener {

  private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
  private WebView mWebView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onUpdateProgress(int progressValue) {
    mProgressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
    if (progressValue == 100) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

}
```

this is webview_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg_progress_bar_history" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

create bg_progress_bar_history.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_second"
        android:scaleWidth="100%" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale
        android:drawable="@color/color_bg_splash"
        android:scaleWidth="100%" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```